# Im trying to read a random line from a text file in discord.js and then post it in the channel where the command ;randomise is asked

Tags: node.js

So basically,

```
require('fs')
require('discord.js')

/**
 * Returns a random number between min (inclusive) and max (exclusive)
 */
function between(min, max) {  
    return Math.floor(
      Math.random() * (max - min) + min
    )
  }
  
  // Example:
  
  var n = (  
    between(1, 55)
  )
  //

  console.log(n)

const nthline = require('node-nthline-master')
    , filePath = '/Users/mesh user/Desktop/discordbot/e/e.txt'
    , rowNumber = n

nthline(rowNumber, filePath)
  .then(line => console.log(line))
```

This code works just fine... But when I tried just sending a random number in a discord channel:

```
C:\Users\mesh user\Desktop\discordbot\main.js:48
    client.commands.get('randomise').execute(message, args, Discord)
                                    ^
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mesh user\Desktop\discordbot\main.js:48:37)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\mesh user\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\mesh user\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\mesh user\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\mesh user\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\mesh user\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\mesh user\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:825:20)
```

BTW here is the test code I ran

```
module.exports = {
name: 'randomisetesting', // Named this for purpose of testing.
description: 'randomise a movie to watch',
execute(message, args){
    require('fs') 
    require('node-nthline-master') 
        /**
         * Returns a random number between min (inclusive) and max (exclusive)
         */
        function between(min, max) {  
            return Math.floor(
              Math.random() * (max - min) + min
            )
          }
          
          // 
          
          var n = (  
            between(1, 55)
          )
          // 
        
          console.log(n)
        message.channel.send(n)
    }}
```

I see something in the error about the lines 48:37 of my main.js file (might be reading that wrong), so i'll also paste the main.js in pastebin because this post is already way too long lol.
https://pastebin.com/3dtSQv8Y

edit: The code I tested actually returns a blank in vscode terminal, I forgot to save it but its still a large problem.

edit2: solved

```
require('fs') 
require('node-nthline-master') 

module.exports = {
name: 'random',
description: 'randomise a movie to watch',
execute(message, args){
        /**
         * Returns a random number between min (inclusive) and max (exclusive)
         */
        function between(min, max) {  
            return Math.floor(
              Math.random() * (max - min) + min
            )
          }
          
          // 
          
          var n = (  
            between(1, 55)
          )
          // 
        

          const nthline = require('node-nthline-master')
    , filePath = '/Users/mesh user/Desktop/discordbot/e/e.txt'
    , rowNumber = n

nthline(rowNumber, filePath)
  .then(line => message.channel.send(line))

    }}
```